# How to make the "Open in the app" IOS bar on the website?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I need to add the same bar(the top one, sorry for RU lang, the bar is using OS language, anyway Открыть equals Open) [FB example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wixHO.jpg), as far as I understand, it is native, so i found a way to add if, adding to

```
 <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=MyAppId(it exists on app store)">
```

After downloading the application and deploying the site locally, I opened it from an iPhone, saw the bar(but it looked different, I was happy, made a screenshot)[My screenshot with working bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNCvT.jpg), but now it has disappeared and I dont know why. Tell me, what could be the problem, why are these panels different(for me and for facebook), maybe I missed a way to use same bar as FB did?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a smart app banner, read this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners for full details. First you need to add this meta tag in the head element of each page you’d like the banner to appear:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, app-argument=myURL">
```

Then implement application(_:open:sourceApplication:annotation:) in your app delegate in which you provide logic that can interpret the URL you pass, this an example from Apple site:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    // In this example, the URL from which the user came is http://example.com/profile/?12345.

    // Determine whether the user was viewing a profile.
    if ([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/profile"]) {

        // Switch to the profile view controller.
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:profileViewController];

        // Pull the profile ID number found in the query string.
        NSString *profileID = [url query];

        // Pass the profile ID number to the profile view controller.
        [profileViewController loadProfile:profileID];

    }
    return YES;
}
```